# Is there a way to set an Azure Web Job parameters (in Azure Portal), and then run it by clicking the "Run" button?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I got an Azure Web Job, and I'd like to run it through the Azure Portal by passing its parameters, and then clicking in the **Run** button. The reason I'd like to do this it's for maintain a friendly way for run the job (for testing purpose especially), and not call the job through its web hook endpoint.

Comment: If the answer works for you, could you please help mark it as an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you already have an azure web app on azure portal. Nav to azure portal -> your web app -> Configuration -> Application settings -> New Application settings, add a parameter name/value:

[image]

Then create a console project(like via visual studio), you can use the following code to get the parameter you set in azure web app Application settings mentioned above:

```
#your other code

var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("your_paramter_set_in_portal");

#your other code
```

Then upload the console project to azure web app.

**Note set the web job Type to Triggered, and set Triggers to Manual .**

[image]

Comment: Perfect Answer..!! 
We can achieve the same using below line as well - 
var environment2 = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("your_paramter_set_in_portal");